# Break Travis-CI build on dotnet test failure

Tags: travis-ci, .net-core, xunit

Doing some proof of concept I've a simple netcore repo with some xUnit tests at [NetCoreXunit](https://github.com/9swampy/NetCoreXunit) that I've got to build on both Appveyor and Travis. I've put in a failing test and Appveyor fails the build but I'm struggling to get Travis to do the same. It executes the tests happily and reports one of the tests fails but passes the build.

I've Googled to death and been trying to pipe and parse the output in a script step in the yaml configuration but my script knowledge is not great.

If anyone could help me get Travis to fail the build I'd be grateful. There's a link from the GitHub repo to both my Appveyor and Travis builds and if you commit to the repo it should build automatically.

--UPDATE--
So I got it as far as parsing the output of two test assemblies and correctly identifying if there's been a test failure; but I need to create a variable so both assemblies get tested before throwing the exit. I've had to jump through silly hoops to get this far; and one was I can't seem to define a variable without Travis complaining. It's also hardcoded and I'd like to extend it to finding all test assemblies not just the hardcoded.

```
after_success:
  # Run tests
  - dotnet test ./src/NetCoreXunit -xml ./out/NetCoreXunit.xml;
    if grep -q 'result="Fail"' ./out/NetCoreXunit.xml ;  then
      echo 'Failed tests detected.';
    else
      echo 'All tests passed.';
    fi;
  - dotnet test ./src/NetCoreXunitB -xml ./out/NetCoreXunitB.xml;
    if grep -q 'result="Fail"' ./out/NetCoreXunitB.xml ;  then
      echo 'Failed tests detected.';
    else
      echo 'All tests passed.';
    fi;
```

Any advice appreciated: how do I get a list of all test assemblies and how do I declare and set a bool that I can then exitcode with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spent way to long trying to get .travis.yml to work; should have just gone straight down the Python route; works as follows called out to from the yml.

```
import os
import sys
import re
from subprocess import call

root_directory = os.getcwd()
print (root_directory)

regexp = re.compile(r'src[\/\\]NetCoreXunit.?$')
result = False
for child in os.walk(root_directory):
    print (child[0])
    if regexp.search(child[0]) is not None:
        print ("Matched")
        test_path = os.path.join(root_directory, child[0])
        if os.path.isdir(test_path):
            print ("IsDir")
            print (test_path)
            os.chdir(test_path)
            call (["dotnet", "test", "-xml", "output.xml"])
            if 'result="Fail"' in open("output.xml").read():
                print (test_path + ": Failed tests detected")
                result = True
            else:
                print (test_path + ": All tests passed")

os.chdir(root_directory)

if result:
    print ("Failed tests detected")
    sys.exit(1)
```